# Check if user is trying to close app through task manager

Tags: javascript, electron, taskmanager

I want to check if the user is trying to close the app through the task manager, I have an app, developed in javascript with electron, and it does something when it's being closed, but if the user closes it through the task manager, it doesn't execute it, bc it can't see if it's being closed or not.
I would like to know if there is any way to make it to check always if it's being closed.

On my main proccess I already have the
`app.on('window-all-closed', async function () {}` but it doesn't do what I need to

Comment: Are you intending to use SQL Login authentication or Windows Authentication? Have you tried using `user` and `password` (SQL Login) or `trustedConnection` (Windows Authentication), but not both at the same time?

Comment: Also, `var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');` should probably be `var sql = require('msnodesqlv8');`

Comment: Also also, [msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8) notes in the Getting Started documentation that when using Electron you'll need to recompile the module with [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild).